# RPi 3B (not +) image on RPI 2

Tags: pi-3, pi-2

I have OctoPrint running on my Pi 3 Ok withou any issues.
Should I be able to boot the same image on a Pi 2?

David

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: Shut down the RPi 3B, pull out the SD Card, put it into the RPi 2 and power it on. Please tell me if it runs.

Answer (score -1):

That's what I was trying putting a card initialized and working fine on an RPi 3 into an RPi 2 and it would not boot.
Same card booted fine in an RPi 3.
RPi 2 boots fine from cards set up on an RPi 2.

It looks as if cards initialized on an RPi 3 will not work on an RPi 2.

Regards

Dave

Comment: That is not true. Does your RPi2 boot from a fresh copy of plain Raspbian. How does the RPi3 SDCard fail? Have you been mucking about running `sudo rpi-update`? Does the card have the ARM6, ARM7 & ARM8 kernels? Are the /lib/modules/* intact?